# Cannot find reason: React: Redirects onclick does not work but other redirects work(Link works and history.push also works)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-dom

All the other redirects (conditional redirects) work perfectly but not the one in the button
(using `<Link>` works perfectly fine)
**Doesnot redirect when the button is clicked**

I have implemented one more redirect in another page on a button click and it works perfectly fine

```js
 render() {
    const { props } = this

    if (this.props.isauthed) {
      if (this.state.usertype == 'user') {
        return <Redirect to='/user' />
      } else {
        if (this.state.usertype == 'customer') {
          return <Redirect to='/customer' />
        } else {
          return (

            <div >
              <Button onClick={() => {<Redirect to='/user' />}}>click here if you are a user</Button>

              <Button onClick={() => {<Redirect to='/customer'/>}}>click here if you are a customer</Button>

            </div>
          )
        }
      }
    } else {
      return <Redirect to='/login' />
    }

  }
```

Comment: Have you considered using a `<Link>` component?

Comment: yes, <Link> works perfectly fine

Comment: I wanted to know the reason why this happens because Redirect in onclick works in all my other pages but not this one

Comment: Because in all other ones *you're returning a* `<Redirect …/>`, in other words rendering it. But when you click the button, you are not rendering a `<Redirect/>`, you're simply creating one

Comment: Got it, Thanks man amazing